# Internal versus external factory

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory

I'm pondering one of two different ways of implementing the factory pattern in PHP. I don't know if these variants have proper names so for now I'm going to call them internal factory and external factory.

Internal factory: The factory method is implemented in the class itself as a static public method

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    protected
        $loadedProps = false;

    public static factory ($id)
    {
        $class = get_called_class ();
        $item = new $class ($id);
        if ($item -> loadedProps ())
        {
            return ($item);
        }
    }

    public function loadedProps ()
    {
        return ($this -> loadedProps);
    }

    protected function loadPropsFromDB ($id)
    {
        // Some SQL logic goes here
    }

    protected function __construct ($id)
    {
        $this -> loadedProps = $this -> loadPropsFromDB ($id);
    }
}
?>
```

External factory: The factory and the items it initializes are implemented as separate entities

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    protected
        $loadedProps = false;

    public function loadedProps ()
    {
        return ($this -> loadedProps);
    }

    protected function loadPropsFromDB ($id)
    {
        // Some SQL logic goes here
    }

    public function __construct ($id)
    {
        $this -> loadedProps = $this -> loadPropsFromDB ($id);
    }
}

abstract class FooFactory 
{
    public static factory ($id)
    {
        $item = new Foo ($id);
        if ($item -> loadedProps ())
        {
            return ($item);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now it seems to me that each has its merits.

The former allows you to hide the constructor from the outside world.  This means the only way you could create a Foo object is via the factory.  If the item's state can't be loaded from the DB then the factory will return NULL which you can check for easily in code.

```
if ($item = Foo::factory ($id))
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // The item failed to load.  Handle error here
}
```

The factory can also create objects of any subclass of Foo without any modification.

However, it seems to have some drawbacks.  First the class has to implement the factory, which might be putting responsibilities in the class that really belong elsewhere.  The internal factory version certainly results in a larger class than the external factory version.

As for the external factory, well it's cleaner as the factory isn't in the class itself and I don't have to worry about a class taking on more responsibility than it should.  The external factory may also be better suited to dependency injection.

However, it has its own set of drawbacks.  First and foremost, the constructor of the item to be built in the factory must be public as PHP doesn't have a concept of packages and no 'package' protection level for class members.  This means there's nothing stopping a coder from just doing new Foo () and bypassing the factory (This may make unit testing easier, though).

The other problem is that FooFactory can only create Foo objects, not any of its subclasses.  This could be got around by adding another parameter to the FooFactory to specify a class name, but then the factory will have to do internal checks that the specified object class is in fact a descendant of Foo.

So basically, what are the relative merits of the two approaches, and which would you recommend?

Also, if they have more proper names than internal or external factory, I'd like to know them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, Factories are established Creational Design Patterns, so you can read about their purpose in the GoF Book or at [Sourcemaking:](http://sourcemaking.com/creational_patterns)

- **Abstract Factory** - Creates an instance of several families of classes
- **Builder** - separates object construction from its representation
- **Factory Method** - Creates an instance of several derived classes
- **Object Pool** - Avoid expensive acquisition and release of resources by recycling objects that are no longer in use
- **Prototype** - A fully initialized instance to be copied or cloned

There is some overlap in these patterns, especially between Factory Method, Abstract Factory and Builder and the distinction is even more blurry when you are not creating families of objects, but just one type of object. So yes, for simplicity, let's assume internal and external factory are the right terms.

Personally, I would always favor an External Factory over an Internal Factory due to the reason you already gave: I can use [Dependency Injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) and can [separate the responsibilities](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Since [static methods are death to testability](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html) and can be [considered harmful](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html) due to the coupling they introduce, I would make the Factory a real object though instead and use non-static methods.

The two drawbacks you mention are not really drawbacks at all.

I cannot think of a reason why I would want to [prevent a developer](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DirectingAttitude.html) from instantiating objects that a Factory creates. In fact, when [Unit-Testing](http://www.phpunit.de/) I will want to create that object on my own and replace any dependencies with [Mocks and Stubs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/test-doubles.html). [I also dont believe that developers should be babysitted too much](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EnablingAttitude.html). Given the script nature of PHP, changing the ctor from private to public is way too easy to be effectively prevented anyways.

As for the other problem of the Factory being unable to create other classes, that's not true. The idea of a Factory actually is to create various types of a family of objects. Even the Factory Method is explicitly allowed to create subclasses. Whether you implement that with a switch/case or with various methods on the factory is up to you. There is also no reason not to combine Factories with Builders or having Factories of Factories that in turn encapsulate the logic to create an object. Thus eliminating the need for any of the internal checks you mention (which could also be met with typehints).

The other viable alternative to Factories would be to use a [Dependency Injection Container](http://picocontainer.org/), like the [Symfony Components DIC](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/) and manage your objects through that container mostly.

Comment: `Off-topic:` On a random note I find it humorous that you both are talking about the same thing when you also have the same username. For a second I thought you were talking to yourself.

Comment: @Tek yeah, Gordon answering Gordon. But I'm Gordon™ :)